# On Linux and by python,what makes a socket timeout?

Tags: python, linux, sockets

I program a server to send datas to a client by python, the code is as follow:

server.py

```
import socket,time
sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)  #just for test
sock.bind(("10.144.74.182",8080))
sock.listen(10)
s,info=sock.accept()
s.settimeout(60)
while 1:
  try:
     t=time.time()
     s.send("a"*4096)
     print time.time()-t
  except:
     print time.time()-t
     break
```

client.py

```
import socket,time
sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(("10.144.74.182",8080))
while 1:
   time.sleep(5)
   a=sock.recv(4096)
```

part output of the program:

[image]

however,the server timed out when running the program.My question is why the server timed out if the network is good? Will the client receives data every 5 seconds lead to server time out?

through tcpdump,I find the reason that when the tcp recv window size of the client is greater then zero again, the client will not notify the server immediately and it will notify the server until it's recv window size greater than a certain value,which can be seen from the follow pic:

[image]

from the pic we can see the client noitfy the server when it's window size is 26368.Is there any one know the threshold value of the recv window size that makes client to notify the server?

Comment: Don't use `timeout` if you want tracing clients. Another point is `timeout` only work on single packet(not whole communication).

Comment: what do you mean by saying "not whole communication"?

Comment: Timeout usually defines whether the connection exists or the system's longest wait time. This time-out is only available for individual packets. It is not used in a file or stream control because the network's status and accessibility of resources are not stable. For this reason, additional data blocks and flags are used in socket applications. If a connection to high speed and amplen is to be established, the timeout function will not work (ignored). If a critical data connection is to be made, the status and line load information is exchanged at certain time intervals (< 200 milliseconds).

Answer (score 0):

The "timeout" you are observing here  is due to flow-control occurring on the TCP socket.  In order to have ordered guaranteed delivery, TCP needs to have a receiver queue (at client.py), and a sender queue (at server.py).  If the client does not read data fast enough, first the receiver queue will fill up, and then the sender queue will fill up.  At that point, once both queues are full, the server will block when it calls `s.send`, and will remain blocked until space becomes available in the sending queue.

If on linux, you can use netstat command to see socket queue.

```
netstat -plan | grep ESTABLISHED | grep 8080
```

E.g. output will look like (I added headers manually):

```
Proto  Recv-Q   Send-Q  Local Address     Foreign Address  State       PID/Program name
tcp    795855        0  127.0.0.1:33652   127.0.0.1:8080   ESTABLISHED 1529/python     
tcp        0   2743089  127.0.0.1:8080    127.0.0.1:33652  ESTABLISHED 1525/python
```

... here, can see non-zero numbers for the Recv-Q and Send-Q, suggesting they have already become full, and so the sender cannot send until the receiver has read some.